# How to properly use parameters in git aliases?

Tags: git, parameter-passing, alias, git-config, git-alias

I have the following git alias in my .gitconfig file.

```
    clone-with-branches = "!cloneWithBranches() { \
        git clone $1 $2 ; \
    }; cloneWithBranches"
```

I am supposed to use it as follows:

```
git clone-with-branches folder1 folder2
```

(supposing that folder1 is valid working git repository that is accessible with its relative path)

when in command line I type,

```
git clone folder1 folder2
```

I indeed obtain a clone of folder1 in folder2
but when I used the alias:

```
git clone-with-branches folder1 folder2
```

I obtain an error

```
fatal: repository 'folder1' does not exist.
```

Can anyone tell me what I missed please?

Comment: When you run `git clone-with-branches`, what directory ("folder", but **the full path name** is important) do you expect the `git clone` to be in when it is run? Note that aliases run from the top level of the work-tree. If that's not what you expect, search for the word `GIT_PREFIX` in the `git config` documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Torek for the hint.
I modified the script as below and then the alias woks perfectly.

```
    clone-with-branches = "!cloneWithBranches() { \
        git clone $GIT_PREFIX$1 $GIT_PREFIX$2 ; \
    }; cloneWithBranches"
```

Please note that GIT_PREFIX is already set within Git and does not have to be set manually (cf http://schacon.github.io/git/git-config.html section alias.* )